# how to apply css only on horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

i'm a new intern and they gave a simple task: personalize the horizontal scrollbar

[image: example]

i have this code, but the vertical scrollbar disappears... i need it to be default on the vertical... only the horizontal scrollbar have to be personalized.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
   border-radius: 8px;
   background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.5);
  }
```

if i put the code below in the middle, the vertical scrollbar will be personalized too... so i can only get this personalized or hide it at all... and i can't do that

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {                             
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: This was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69116423/10906012

Comment: with this solution my vertical scrollbar will be customized too... I need it not to be changed, need it to be default :(

Comment: Did you check that `::-webkit-scrollbar` has added `:horizontal` too?

Comment: for some reason, when i add :horizontal on ::-webkit-scrollbar, the CSS does't apply either in the horizontal or vertical... it's like i haven't added it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the pseudo decorator with the div to apply the style.
It means the vertical thumb is from the body or HTML tag. And the horizontal thumb is for an inner div.

```css
#bars-chart-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}
#bars-chart-container
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.5);
}
```

This probably won't prevent the vertical thumb of the inner div will disappear, but so far I see in your images, you don't need to show that. And I don't see that could be in another way.

Comment: I can't quite see how this answers the question, which requires the vertical scrollbar to keep its default styling and the horizontal scrollbar to be styled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to style horizontal scrollbar only:

https://codepen.io/lmmm/pen/abKeEJw

You can use the element which you want to style, and use your rules as you want:

```html
<div id="horizontal">
    horizontal text that overflows
</div>
```

```css
#horizontal::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}
#horizontal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```