# How to design scrollbar design in horizontally in CSS?

Tags: css

I tried such a things where I wanted to controll or design the website / browser scrollbar width by CSS. I know how to controll the scrollbar width, but it only works for vertical scrollbar, not for horizontal. How can I controll it ?

Here's my approach:
`::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 10px; }`

but it only works for vertical, not for horizontal scrollbar. For that;[image]

How can I make it thin ? I mean scrollbar thin in width (Horizontally).

Tried to make scrollbar thin in horizontally.

Comment: You mean the height of the scrollbar to make it thinner? Maybe this will help you [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-scrollbar-tutorial/]

Comment: Here's another link within stackoverflow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334106/how-can-i-style-horizontal-scrollbar-by-css]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **'height'** for the horizontal scrollbar. like

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 5px;}
    }
```

You can customise the appearance further using the following styles:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f0f0f0; 
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```